# loading another tableview when a tablecell of one tableview is clicked returning error:"Program received signal SIGABRT"

Tags: xcode4, uitableview

I am creating an app in which there are two UIViews and in those UIViews I am loading Tableviews..
When I click a tablecell in one TableView then I am unable to redirect it to another TableView and getting error:Program received signal SIGABRT.But if I want to load a UIView when a tablecell is clicked it gets executed perfectly.I couldn't understand where Am I going wrong....
This is the code i'm writing

```
 ViewController1:
   #import ViewController2.h"

     -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        ViewController2 *v2 = [ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self presentModalViewController:v2 animated:NO]; **//getting error at this line**
        [v2 release];

    }
    ViewController2.h
    #import"ViewController1.h"
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   tableView1 = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 320, 460)];
    tableView1.delegate = self;
    tableView1.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView1]; 

   }
```

Couldn't understand what could be the possible cause of this error..

Comment: Don't call `alloc` without then calling some form of `init...` method...whichever one is appropriate for your object.

Comment: Can u please explain briefly.I couldn't get u

Comment: You are allocating memory for your `GetAppointments` object but then not initializing it.  If you look at **any** sample code for creating a view controller, it should have something like `[[GetAppointments alloc] init<#...some type of initialization...>];`.

Comment: I edited the code but still no luck

Comment: The "code" you have posted wouldn't even compile.  (`ViewController2 *v2 = [ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];`)  I'm not going to make guesses about what might be wrong with something I can't see.

Comment: what extra code should I display here otherwise which makes u to have a quick look on it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the bug

```
    ViewController2 *v2 = [ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

You have allocated ViewController instead of **ViewController2**

Try this and it should work, I guess.

```
    ViewController2 *v2 = [ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Comment: ok, you should also check whether all the IBOutlets are connected properly in the .xib file or not by right clicking the File's Owner.